# Refere NetworkManage.Service Start Up Works?

Tags: networkmanager

Can anyone help me answer the following questions about **the specific work done when Linux NetworkManager.Service is started**? The more detailed the better.

I want to know the content of this section, but I can’t find the official document. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Also please make sure you are not asking a [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) question.